# Event for "end edit" in a text box

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am using a textbox in winform (c#) and using the text to make consults in a database.

But I need constantly consult the text of the textbox every time that text changes. So for these, I use the KeyUp. But this event is too slow.

Is any event that just fires when the textbox editing has been finished ?. I consider for finish 2 conditions

The control lost focus.
The control has 200ms without keypress

Comment: What do consider 'finished'? You could use a timer that is reset in the `KeyUp` event, or the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: You could set a timer to run some time after the last key has been pressed. If during the countdown the user presses another key you reset the countdown. If it is allowed to finish then you run your database query. This technique ensures that, given a properly tuned countdown time duration, you'll run your query while the user has paused during typing.

Comment: TheX i am looking something like that.

Comment: This sounds like there might be a simpler solution. Can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event, to capture when the user clicks on a control outside the textbox.

Otherwise, you'll need to choose from one of the existing events.  ([Listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx))

Come to think of it, you will likely have to capture multiple events.  DragDrop if someone copies/pastes, for example...

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

[Control.LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx)

Provided that you consider finished as being when they click off the textbox.

Comment: Beat me by 23 seconds.  +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks :) and +1 to you too!