# How to register event for TextBox end editing

Tags: c#, events, winrt-xaml

Super newbie to C# (first day coding), so please don't judge me too much if the following is really a stupid question to you.

But I am looking for a way to register an event for when a TextBox end editing, which is similar [`textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:) delegate in iOS.

After some googling around, I know how to register an textChanged event with the following:

In **.xaml** file:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler"/>
```

In **.cs** file:

```
protected void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{

}
```

I also notice this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420810/), and finally this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by MS and notice this following function:

```
// This method handles the LostFocus event for textBox1 by setting the  
// dialog's InitialDirectory property to the text in textBox1. 
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // ... 
}
```

But what is not obvious to me is how do I register this event function? Or how do I let the GUI know to call this function when the TextBox end editing?

---

This is finally what it takes for it to work:

In **.xaml** file:

```
<TextBox LostFocus="textFinishedEditingEventHandler"/>
```

In **.cs** file:

```
public void textFinishedEditingEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thanks to @Dacker!~

Comment: What do you mean by 'how do I register this function'? Your xaml and cs snippets tell me you already did that. If you run this code, changing the text in the textbox will fire the event handler.

Comment: Hello, @venerik. I want to register event for "text finish editing" rather than for "text changed". Dacker's answer is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an event can be registered in two ways:

In markup. In ASP.Net each type of event is exposed with the prefix On, so for Click it's OnClick. In your xaml I don't see the On prefix, so that makes me guess it is the following in your case:

```
<TextBox LostFocus="textBox1_LostFocus" />
```

In code behind (.cs)

```
textBox1.LostFocus += textBox1_LostFocus
```

If you understand this, you can use better names for textBox1_LostFocus to describe more what will happen instead of when it will happen.

Comment: I would just like to add that the LostFocus event will fire only when the user taps or clicks on some other control and the other control gets focus. It will not fire when the user just stops typing.

Comment: I am getting this error: **error CS0123: No overload for 'textBox1_LostFocus' matches delegate 'Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler'**. Any idea what's going one?

Comment: If it's a RoutedEventHandler the delegate is specified to accept a RoutedEventArgs instead of EventArgs. Change your signature of textBox1_LostFocus to expect RoutedEventArgs: private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)